# Scala REPL issue - Multiexpression issue

Tags: scala

I am new to scala and getting below exception while using :paste command in REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

1+2
println("welcome to scala world")

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:11: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; multiline expressions may require enclosing parentheses
       1+2
        ^
welcome to scala world
```

scala> 
scala version : Scala code runner version 2.12.3 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc

Comment: This seems like expected behavior to me.

Comment: I came to this question because of this Scastie snippet: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VFCGmgfjTECkymOJoHW85Q There should be an exception on line 23 and the pure expression warning on line 39. If you replace `invalidFunctionF` with `square`, the exception disappears, but the pure expression warning persists...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an exception, just a warning that you can ignore. It warns that in paste mode the expression `1+2` has no effect and the result won't be printed.
If you would enter both of your lines in normal mode the REPL will print the result of each expression.

```
scala> 1+2
res1: Int = 3

scala> println("welcome to scala world")
welcome to scala world
```

The second part of the warning is for the case that you intend a multi-line expression where each line is a valid expression, e.g.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

1+2
-5

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<console>:48: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be     omitting necessary parentheses
       1+2
        ^
res1: Int = -5
```

which is different from

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

(1+2
-5)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

res22: Int = -2
```